# Azure Static Web Apps CLI work with my blazor client app with an azure functions API

Tags: azure-functions, blazor-webassembly, swa-cli

I have been trying to get Azure Static Web Apps CLI work with my blazor client app with an azure functions api. I can not debug locally and hit break points.

I have the most up to date version of the SWA CLI.

When I run

```
swa --version
```

I get back the result.

```
1.0.3
```

In the solution I have both the Api and the Client app set to start on debug

When I run it I get

```
Azure Functions Core Tools
Core Tools Version:       4.0.4865 Commit hash: N/A  (64-bit)
Function Runtime Version: 4.12.2.19454

[2022-11-10T21:03:29.331Z] Found C:\github\xxx\Api\Api.csproj. Using for user secrets file configuration.

Functions:

        Function1: [GET,POST] http://localhost:7129/api/Function1

        WeatherForecast: [GET] http://localhost:7129/api/weather-forecast/{daysToForecast=5}
```

When I go to http://localhost:7129/api/weather-forecast/ it runs okay and hits my breakpoints
When debingging the browser opens at https://localhost:5000 I browse to the razor page that calls

```
forecasts = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<WeatherForecast[]>("api/weather-forecast/5");
```

I get

```
''<' is an invalid start of a value. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 0.'
```

I expect this is because its returning a html page and is the reason that I should be using “Azure Static Web Apps CLI”

I have run the following in a new terminal widow and in the Developer PowerShell in visual studio 2022

**Option 1**

With the app running in debug from visual studio
In a terminal window running from the root directory of the project

```
swa start http://localhost:5000
```

This give me

```
***********************************************************************
* WARNING: This emulator may not match the cloud environment exactly. *
* Always deploy and test your app in Azure.                           *
***********************************************************************

[swa]
[swa] Using dev server for static content:
[swa]   https://localhost:5000/
[swa]
[swa] Azure Static Web Apps emulator started at http://localhost:4280. Press CTRL+C to exit.
[swa]
[swa]
```

I browse to http://localhost:4280 and then the terminal window does

```
[swa] GET https://localhost:5000//fetchdata (proxy)
[swa] node "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@azure\static-web-apps-cli\dist\msha\server.js" exited with code 0
```

**Option 2**

With the app running in debug from visual studio
In a terminal window running from the root directory of the project

```
swa init
```

Which give

```
Welcome to Azure Static Web Apps CLI (1.0.3)

? Choose a configuration name: » zzz
Detected configuration for your app:
- Framework(s): Blazor WASM, with API: .NET
- App location: Client
- Output location: bin\wwwroot
- API location: Api
- App build command: dotnet publish -c Release -o bin
- API build command: dotnet publish -c Release
- App dev server command: dotnet watch run
- App dev server URL: http://localhost:8000

? Are these settings correct? » (Y/n)
```

Then I entered

```
Swa start
```

Which gave

```
[api] Azure Functions Core Tools
[api] Core Tools Version:       4.0.4865 Commit hash: N/A  (32-bit)
[api] Function Runtime Version: 4.12.2.19454
[api]
[api] [2022-11-10T21:25:12.343Z] Found C:\GitHub\xxx\Api\Api.csproj. Using for user secrets file configuration.
[api]
[api] Functions:
[api]
[api]   Function1: [GET,POST] http://localhost:7071/api/Function1
[api]
[api]   WeatherForecast: [GET] http://localhost:7071/api/weather-forecast/{daysToForecast=5}
[api]
[api] For detailed output, run func with --verbose flag.
[api] [2022-11-10T21:25:18.072Z] Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '0000000000000000000000003FF48B6B'.
✖ Waiting for http://localhost:8000 to be ready
[swa] ✖ Could not connect to "http://localhost:8000". Is the server up and running?
[swa] node "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@azure\static-web-apps-cli\dist\msha\server.js" exited with code 0
--> Sending SIGTERM to other processes..
[api] cd "C:\GitHub\zzz\Api" && C:\Users\Ashley\.swa\core-tools\v4\func start --cors "*" --port 7071  exited with code 1
--> Sending SIGTERM to other processes..
[run] cd "C:\GitHub\zzz\Client" && dotnet watch run exited with code 1
✖ SWA emulator stoped because the --run command exited with code 1.
```

So gave up on that avenue

**Option 3**

With the app running in debug from visual studio
In a terminal window running from the root directory of the project

```
swa start https://localhost:5000 --api-location http://localhost:7129
```

which gave

```
Welcome to Azure Static Web Apps CLI (1.0.3)

***********************************************************************
* WARNING: This emulator may not match the cloud environment exactly. *
* Always deploy and test your app in Azure.                           *
***********************************************************************

[swa]
[swa] Using dev server for static content:
[swa]   https://localhost:5000
[swa]
[swa] Using dev server for API:
[swa]   http://localhost:7129
[swa]
[swa] Azure Static Web Apps emulator started at http://localhost:4280. Press CTRL+C to exit.
[swa]
[swa]
```

I browse to http://localhost:4280/
And the page is This site can’t be reached
And the terminal says

```
[swa] GET https://localhost:5000/fetchdata (proxy)
[swa] node "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@azure\static-web-apps-cli\dist\msha\server.js" exited with code 0
```

I have tried the most up to date version of node.js and a few older ones, to rule that out being the issue.

I can not work out how to get the front end and api to work together with this tool, with the guide I am working through I have the feeling I will need to get them working for things later on.

---

Update

---

It seems to work if you use the http port number instead of the https port number.... not sure what that will mean going forward.

Comment: Hi Ashley, it seems like something is breaking with azure function core tools v4 with Node18 installed. Please have a look [link](https://github.com/Azure/static-web-apps-cli/issues/598)

Comment: Hi Ashley, I am facing the exact same issue with React 18 / Node.js 16.  Could it be this bug? https://github.com/Azure/static-web-apps-cli/issues/609